# How to solve problem with initialization problem in subclass

Tags: python, type-conversion, annotations, subclass

Faced with such a problem, made a custom type for working with data, I attach the code

```
class Number:
  pass

class uint16_t(Number):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.bit_size = 16
        super().__init__(value)
        
class uint32_t(Number):
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        self.bit_size = 32
        super().__init__(value)

class Foo:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        for field_name, field_type in cls.__annotations__.items():
            print(field_type)
            val = getattr(cls, field_name)
            if issubclass(field_type, Number):
                val = field_type(val)
            setattr(cls, field_name, val)

class Bar(Foo):
    first: uint32_t
    second: uint16_t
```

Call

```
obj = Bar(first=10, second=5)
```

But, i get

```
Line 21, in Foo.__init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs)
     19 for field_name, field_type in cls.__annotations__.items():
     20     print(field_type)
---> 21     val = getattr(cls, field_name)
     22     if issubclass(field_type, Number):
     23         val = field_type(val)
     24     setattr(cls, field_name, val)

AttributeError: type object 'Bar' has no attribute 'first'
```

Comment: Please provide more details, including full error traceback. This error references different code than the one you provided.

Comment: Only this makes sense
in __init_subclass__
    val = getattr(self, field_name)
AttributeError: type object 'Bar' has no attribute 'first'

Comment: The error message "AttributeError: type object 'DateTime' has no attribute 'year'" indicates that there is a reference to an attribute named 'year' in your code, but the attribute or class 'DateTime' doesn't seem to be defined in the provided code snippet. Without the complete context and code, it's a bit challenging to identify the exact source of the error. Could you please provide more context and details about the code where you're encountering this error?

Comment: I have everything defined, I just changed the names of the real classes

Comment: The problem is that you are trying the get the attribute `first` before it is initialized. Moreover if I understand your code, you will execute `uint32_t('first')` while `uint32_t` constructor expects an integer.

Comment: It's solution correct, but i need do it in __init_subclass__
My question is more can I get the real value from the subclass in the __init_subclass method in the inherited class__

Comment: @roman by the way, surrounding text with two underscores makes it bold. Surround your function names in backticks to make them look like `this` and allow you to use double-underscores properly, like `__this__`

Comment: Are you aware that `__init_subclass__` runs during the creation of the class and not the instance? `class Bar(Foo) ...` triggers `__init_subclass__` it does not trigger when you do `Bar(first=10, second=5)`. From my understanding you want to access the values of the instance? Can you clarify this in your question if you want to hook on the class-creation or instance-creation

Comment: Yes, I tried to get the value from the fields of the Bar class, and convert these values to the necessary types

Answer (score 0):

Your class Bar does not have an attribute `first` because you do not create it. See this simple reproduction of your error:

```py
class A:
    first: int

print(A.first) # throws AttributeError
```

You try to access `first` with the `getattr` in the `__init_subclass__`-function before you create it. I think you believe you created it because you have the annotation, but this does not do what you think it does.
You do not `declare` anything in python like you do in languages like Java or C, you just assign to names that do not exist yet and that creates the field. So setting `first` to some dummy value would do the trick.

Comment: What is the right thing to do in this case?

Comment: @roman, `__init__` is where you define _instance_-attributes, but you are trying to set _class_-attributes, so no. You can set the dummy value either in the class definition block of `Bar`: `first: uint32_t = dummy`, or in the `__init_subclass__` by not calling `getattr` before setting a value.

Comment: @roman my comment was answering your original comment before the edit, I hope it helps anyways.

Comment: The whole problem is that I can't change the class Bar

Comment: @roman then do the initialization in `__init_subclass__`. You cannot read a variable before you set it, what would you expect to happen? Every variable in every programming language must be set before it can be meaningfully read.